# Move any row to bottom of dataframe based on row index in pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidyverse

How do you move any row to the bottom of a dataframe based on the row index using a dplyr pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in two lines. First line duplicates the desired row to the end of the dataframe using `bind_rows()` and `slice()`. The second line removes the first instance of the now duplicated row using `slice()`.

Here is an example moving the **second** row to the end:

```
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(x = letters[1:4], y = 1:4)

df %>% 
  bind_rows(slice(., 2)) %>% 
  slice(-2)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  x         y
  <chr> <int>
1 a         1
2 c         3
3 d         4
4 b         2
```

Comment: Or all in one `slice`: `slice(c(setdiff(row_number(), 2), 2))`

Answer (score 2):

I am aware that the question specifically states "**based on row index**", however, I found this thread in the context of trying to figure out how to do this based on a **character match** and I found no guidance. Hence I figured out something myself (with the help of [Oliver Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4199944/oliver-oliver)'s post here - Thank you!), which I would like to share.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(x = letters[1:4], y = 1:4)

df %>%
  bind_rows(slice(., which(x != "b")), slice(., which(x == "b"))) %>%
  tail(nrow(.)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient method using dplyr, I believe:

```
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(x = letters[1:4], y = 1:4)

df |> slice(1, c(3:4), 2)
```